VLOOKUP in Python Pandas
A question that has been asked similarly a million times but I cannot find the correct answer that applies to my case.
I have two excel files that I want to join like an Excel VLOOKUP.
File A already has the columns already created and they are partially filled (or empty). There is one column with adresses that will be the Join column for the other Excel file, File B. However, in File A are more addresses than in File B, so File B will only fill the targeted columns based on the values for those addresses, the others should not be affected (so either remain empty or with their old value).
File B has this column with addresses and then the columns with the values that are to be assigned to the respective addresses in File A. There are other columns in File B but I don't want those in File A.
According to my research I need an Inner Left Join to accomplish this. The column in common is AdressID, the columns to merge let's call them AA, BB, CC and DD.
My dataframes are called dfFileA and dfFileB.
I tried the following code:
dfFileA = pd.merge(dfFileA[['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'AdressID']], dfFileB[['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'AdressID']], on=['AdressID'], how='left')

Error message is
KeyError: "['AA', 'BB', 'CC'] not in index"
Where is the mistake?
Thanks a lot!
[EDIT:]
Here is an example of my problem, however, here it creates new columns with the same name but ending on _y and it renamed the original ones ending on _x (I don't know why it does that in this example and not in the original file):
import pandas as pd
FileA = {
'AA' : ['', 'DEF', '', 'JKL'],
'BB' : ['MNO', '', 'STU', ''],
'CC' : ['WX', '', 'GDG', 'GJ'],
'DD' : ['GDSG', 'OFHHJHFS', 'GDJIO', 'GDKOS'],
'EE' : ['GHDH', 'IGHDH', 'GDJG', 'GODJS'],
'AdressID' : ['Great Street 1', 'Amazing Street 5', 'Perfect Street 21', 'Fantastic Street 88']
}

FileB = {
'AA' : ['ABC', '', 'GHI', ''],
'BB' : ['', 'PQR', '', 'FAS'],
'CC' : ['', 'YZ', '', 'GJ'],
'FF' : ['GDSGH', 'GDKOJ', 'GDD', 'GDOKJ'],
'GG' : ['GIOJD', 'GDOK', 'GDJI', 'DGOJ'],
'AdressID' : ['Great Street 1', 'Amazing Street 5', 'Perfect Street 21', 'Fantastic Street 88']
}

dfFileA = pd.DataFrame(FileA)
dfFileB = pd.DataFrame(FileB)

print(dfFileA)
print(dfFileB)

merged = pd.merge(dfFileA, dfFileB, on='AdressID', how='inner')
print(merged)

Obviously, I want the output to be like
merged = {
'AA' : ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'],
'BB' : ['MNO', 'PQR', 'STU', 'FAS'],
'CC' : ['WX', 'YZ', 'GDG', 'GJ'],
'DD' : ['GDSG', 'OFHHJHFS', 'GDJIO', 'GDKOS'],
'EE' : ['GHDH', 'IGHDH', 'GDJG', 'GODJS'],
'AdressID' : ['Great Street 1', 'Amazing Street 5', 'Perfect Street 21', 'Fantastic Street 88']
}

Hope this helps better.
So I only want to keep the columns from FileB that exist also in FileA. Alternatively, I could just delete them selectively after the merge/combine_first.
[Edit:
I modified the example, I should have put more different columns in FileA and FileB that do not exist in the other.

read notice:[mre] plz dont describe, show.

Code
Use combine_first, instead of merge
out = dfFileA.replace('', None).combine_first(dfFileB)

out:
    AA   BB   CC             AdressID
0  ABC  MNO   WX       Great Street 1
1  DEF  PQR   YZ     Amazing Street 5
2  GHI  STU  GDG    Perfect Street 21
3  JKL  FAS   GJ  Fantastic Street 88


Just realized, this did not work. The values of FileB were not added to FileA according to AdressID.  It did fill something but in seemingly random order but it did not take AdressID as reference. Does combine_first assume the same row order of AdressID in FileA and FileB (because that is not the case).

@Kai The answer is based on the [mre]. If the answer you build based on the MRE doesn't solve the actual problem, then the problem is with the MRE, not the answer. Also, combine_first doesn't fill in order, it fills in based on the key.  It only seems to work in order because you have RangeIndex.(which you would have known if you had read the official documentation for combine_first function I linked)  If you want to fill based on AddressID column, set that column to index (but make sure there are no duplicate values)

Setting the index to AdressID did the trick! Thank you!

try this:
import pandas as pd

FileA = {
    'AA' : ['', 'DEF', '', 'JKL'],
    'BB' : ['MNO', '', 'STU', ''],
    'CC' : ['WX', '', 'GDG', 'GJ'],
    'DD' : ['GDSG', 'OFHHJHFS', 'GDJIO', 'GDKOS'],
    'EE' : ['GHDH', 'IGHDH', 'GDJG', 'GODJS'],
    'AdressID' : ['Great Street 1', 'Amazing Street 5', 'Perfect Street 21', 'Fantastic Street 88']
}

FileB = {
    'AA' : ['ABC', '', 'GHI', ''],
    'BB' : ['', 'PQR', '', 'FAS'],
    'CC' : ['', 'YZ', '', 'GJ'],
    'FF' : ['GDSGH', 'GDKOJ', 'GDD', 'GDOKJ'],
    'GG' : ['GIOJD', 'GDOK', 'GDJI', 'DGOJ'],
    'AdressID' : ['Great Street 1', 'Amazing Street 5', 'Perfect Street 21', 'Fantastic Street 88']
}

dfFileA = pd.DataFrame(FileA)
dfFileB = pd.DataFrame(FileB)

merged_df = dfFileA.merge(dfFileB, how='left', on='AdressID', suffixes=('_A', '_B'))
col_name =  dfFileA.columns.intersection(dfFileB.columns).to_list()
col_name.remove('AdressID')
for column in col_name:
    dfFileA[column] = dfFileA[column].where(dfFileA[column] != '', merged_df[f'{column}_B'])

